# Outlook events sent to a google calendar - event ids change unexpectedly?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am creating a meeting series from an outlook client, on an office365 mailbox.
The invited user is on g-suite (email, calendar...).

My code connects to google calendar via the API and periodically checks of event changes \ new events \ cancelled etc.

I store the event ids in my database and use them to match to the event IDs I read from google calendar.

When a whole meeting series is changed - for instance a weekly series gets a new starting time - the event IDs returning from google calendar APIs - change!

I am not sure if the IDs are generated by office\outlook or by g-suite.
I am not sure what's the right way to match the events I stored with their old IDs, to the new events coming in.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Google API Documentation, it states that recurring events are composed of instances. The recurring event is a parent and individual instances are its children. Each child has a `recurringEventId` which identifies its parent. Their individual instance `id`s might change when they are changed.

See the following: https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_or_deleting_instances

Comment: Completely missed this little piece of info. Thanks!!